# Controllerクラス内での標準メソッド利用について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

はじめまして。ruby初心者です。
ruby on rails を利用して webシステムの作成を試みていますが
解決できないエラーがありましたので質問させて頂きます。

作成したcontrollerクラスにて
ransackを使ってDBから取得したString型の文字列を
splitメソッドで分割したいと考えていますがうまくできません。

エラーメッセージは下記のとおりです。

```
undefined local variable or method `“' for #
<HogeController:0x007f9529648cf8>
```

ソースコードは下記のとおりです。

```
 def index
  @q = Hoge.search(params[:q])
  @hoges = @q.result(distinct: true)
  @hoges.each do |a|
  str = a.hogestr.to_s.split(“,”)
  end
end
```

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: `","`を試してみたらどうでしょうか？

Comment: ご指摘ありがとうございます。
Mac標準のテキストエディタで書いていたのですが勝手に変換 ?されていたようだったので、別途エディタで ","を入力してみたら解決しました！
初歩的な質問すみませんでした。。

Answer (score 2):

`“,”` のダブルクォーテーションマークが ASCII の `"` になってないためです。
一度 `“,”` を消して `","` と入力しなおせばいいと思います。